# Ajax PHP checking for existig user in mysql

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to make register page and now I want to check if the user already has an account, but I have a problem. The problem is that when I put echo before the `if(isset)`, the tex is being printed in my website, but after the if statement nothing is happening.

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); 

include("connect.php");
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
 echo "display";
 $username=$_POST['username'];

 $checkdata="SELECT * FROM Register WHERE username='$username'";
 $query=mysqli_query($db,$checkdata);
// if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
// {
  echo '<span class = "text-danger">Username Already Exist</span>';
// }
// else
// {
  echo '<span class = "text-success">Username is available</span>';
// }
  exit();
}
?>
```

and this is my JQuery code:

```
      $('document').ready(function(){
       $('#username').blur(function(){
     var username = $(this).val();
     $.ajax({
         url:"check.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{username :username},
         dataType:"text",
         success:function(html){
             $('#usercheck').html(html);
         }
     });
     });
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can do it this way:

your php script:

```
        if (isset($_POST["action"])) {
    $action = $_POST["action"];
    switch ($action) {
        case 'SLC':
        if (isset($_POST["username"])) {
            $username = $_POST["username"];

            $checkdata="SELECT * FROM Register WHERE username='$username'";
            $query=mysqli_query($db,$checkdata);
            // if(mysql_num_rows($query)>0)
            // {
            echo 'false';
            // }
            // else
            // {
            echo 'true';
            // }
            exit();
        }
    }
    break;
}
```

Where action is a command you want to do SLC, UPD, DEL etc and id is a parameter

then in your ajax:

```
function getAvaliableUser() {
    var value = $('#username').val();
   return $.ajax({
         url:"check.php",
         method:"POST",
         data:{username :username},
         dataType:"text"
});

}
```

call it like this:

```
getAvaliableUser().done(function(response){
var data = response;
//do something with my response and show the span here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Think about it answer:

Since the echo before the isset works, one would assume that `$_POST['username']` is *not* set. Which would lead to here `data:{username :username},` in the js. If the user enters `me` for user name what will that line produce?

Explicit answer

> Doesn't this needs quotes to *define* the key, like `data:{'username' :username},`?